# asp.net global.asax.cs and global.asax difference

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, global-asax

My global.asax file. It seems like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
namespace xxxx
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }    
    }
}
```

but when I look others global.asax file seems as

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>

<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
}
</script>
```

why my global.asax file is different from them ? I use 4.0 framework.When I try routing,my project cant see my route rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "Global.asax" is actually a "Global.asax.cs" - your Global.asax itself will probably look something like this:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="x.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

The `Global.asax.cs` is what's known as a codebehind file. There is no real functional difference between the two approaches - the codebehind is simply designed to separate concerns between markup and server-side code.

This has nothing to do with any routing problems you are having.

Comment: thanks but I have problem about routing.My web page Cannot acces my routerule and show this message "a route named 'xxx' could not be found in the route collection"..I thought it about it.Possible ?

Comment: You should update your question with your full route Global.asax/RegisterRoutes and full stack trace for the error you're receiving.