# What is the difference between global.asax and global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> Tell me about the difference between global.asax and global.asax.cs ?

and

> If i click the both file in my solution explorer , it's goes to only server (asax.cs) side ,Why and how ? and can i see client side(global.asax) page ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120425/asp-net-global-asax-cs-and-global-asax-difference

Comment: The difference is the same from aspx file and aspx.cs file. one is the client side file and the other one is the server side file. the global.asax is the general definition of you web application on sessions states and application states. It doesn't have a client site. the client file the global.asax just there to call the global class in the cs file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Global.asax is the markup file that goes with the "code-behind" file .asax.cs.  But the markup file isn't used for much, as far as I know (all the content normally goes into the code-behind file).  You can view it, though, by right-clicking on it in Solution Explorer, and then "view markup".

You can't add content to the markup, only a few attributes:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
                Inherits="WebApplication1.Global" 
                Language="C#" %>
```

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) seem to confirm that the only purpose of global.asax is to add/override handlers for application-level events:

> The Global.asax file, also known as the ASP.NET application file, is an optional file that contains code for responding to application-level events raised by ASP.NET or by HttpModules.

Comment: @RameshRajendran no, I'm pretty sure you can't add any controls -- just a few attributes.

Comment: Okay !! I will check it sir .... Thanks for your answer , It's understandable answer ....

Comment: Yes , It's not got it. But i have one doubt, The aspx file have page ,but asax have application . what is the difference ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran well, .aspx instantiates a page, while .asax instantiates an HttpApplication object.  But unlike a page, an application can't be loaded by the user, but only internally by the ASP.Net runtime.  Global.asax is an extensibility point -- it allows you to override application-level event handlers.

Comment: See jbl's answer below for why this answer is not exactly correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can hit F7 when in codebehind file to display `.asax` markup.

The `global.asax` behaves somewhat like an aspx file, being compiled when the application starts.

You can even put your methods (like `Application_Start`) in a `script runat="server"` element in the `global.asax.`

I doubt it is good practice, but this should allow to *hot-edit* a running application (which should trigger a recycle I guess) It will then be compiled dynamically.

Comment: @RameshRajendran It might depend on your settings (been using it for a while. See key bindings here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13189) On my plateform (VS2012), it just allows to  go from asax.cs to asax, and not the reverse. shift+f7 has no effect at all

Comment: Okay , I was right click and see the view mark .. it's okay.... I have one doubt for ,what is the different between application and page ? asax have application aspx have page ? why ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran pages, web-services, handlers, etc can be seen as basic components. The application is the container which states general organization  of the different components being served (with routing, session state, error handling, configuration, ...). You can see the application as a shop, which organizes access to products (the pages) being sold.

Answer (score 2):

The global.asax.cs is what's known as a codebehind file of global.asax. There is no real functional difference between the two of those files.The codebehind is simply designed to separate concerns between markup and server-side code.