# How to add Global.asax file without the .cs file in existing web form web application

Tags: c#, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5

Let me first make it clear so this question is not marked as duplicate. 
I am having a web form web application. I am already having a Global.asax file which consist of a Global.asax.cs file. I am converting my application to MVC 5 and so I need Global.asax file only which can having all the initialising method. If I add new Item in visual studio it provides me with an option of Global Application class. If I add that again I get Global.asax with .cs file. I require only and only Global.asax.

Comment: You probably should read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488420/what-is-the-difference-between-global-asax-and-global-asax-cs

Comment: The Above link is the actual answer.